# How to make an EJB reach a Vaadin UI

Tags: java, multithreading, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I wonder how to make an EJB Timer be able to reach my Vaadin UI to update a GUI component once the job in background is done.

Is there any way to get it? I tried to get the UI using UI.getCurrent() in my EJB method, but it returns null.

I noticed that getCurrent() method looks up in a InheritableThreadLocal map for all current instances, but my guess is the EJB thread is not associated to my UI Thread.

Let my any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just store a reference to the UI instance somewhere?

Comment: Look at the Broadcast example in the `book of vaadin`: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html#advanced.push.pusharound

Comment: I already tried to use Broadcast ,but UI instance returns null as well.

Comment: Could you share your code, so we can have a look at what're you doing ?

Comment: I found out ejb and vaadin are in different containers,  for example ejb can not access a thread running in a web container.